# How to prevent multiple clicks

Tags: jquery

Just like in the picture below, there's an empty value that insert in the database because of multiple click in save button. How I can prevent multiple clicks so empty data can't insert on my database?

Any help will appreciate!!

[image]

Here my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save").click(function(){
        ajax("save");
    });

    $("#add_new").click(function(){
        $(".entry-form").fadeIn("fast");    
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast");   
    });

    $("#cancel").click(function(){
        $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast");   
    });

    $(".del").live("click",function(){
        if(confirm("Do you really want to delete this record ?")){
            ajax("delete",$(this).attr("id"));
        }
    });

    function ajax(action,id){
        if(action =="save")
            data = $("#userinfo").serialize()+"&action="+action;
        else if(action == "delete"){
            data = "action="+action+"&item_id="+id;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "ajax.php", 
            data : data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                if(response.success == "1"){
                    if(action == "save"){
                        $(".entry-form").fadeOut("fast",function(){
                            $(".table-list").append("<tr><td>"+response.cat_name+"</td><td>"+response.cat_code+"</td><td>"+response.letter+"</td><td><a href='#' id='"+response.row_id+"' class='del'>Delete</a></td></tr>");   
                            $(".table-list tr:last").effect("highlight", {
                                color: '#4BADF5'
                            }, 0000);
                        }); 
                        $(".entry-form input[type='text']").each(function(){
                            $(this).val("");
                        });                     
                    }else if(action == "delete"){
                        var row_id = response.item_id;
                        $("a[id='"+row_id+"']").closest("tr").effect("highlight", {
                            color: '#4BADF5'
                        }, 0000);
                        $("a[id='"+row_id+"']").closest("tr").fadeOut();
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("unexpected error occured, Please check your database connection");
                }
            },
            error: function(res){
                alert("Unexpected error! Try again.");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: add `disable` onclick...

Answer (score 0):

Once validation is return success, unbind the event handler.

```
$("#save").click(function(){

//Asuming your form validation is success.
 $('#save').unbind( "click" );
//Change the style to indicate it was dissabled.

        ajax("save");
    });
```

Comment: why not disable the button once click?

Comment: @senthil yah it works, but the new problems came in, when I try to add new record again the save button still disable. I need to refresh before I add new records

Comment: Aganin you can enable the click hander by using .on method   $(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
     ajax("save");
});

Comment: @senthil where should I place the on method?

Comment: It should be inside $("#add_new").click(

Comment: @senthil like this?  $("#add_new").click(function(){
  $(".entry-form").fadeIn("fast");
 jQuery_1_9_1(document).on('click', '#save', function() { ajax("save"); }); 
 });

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false;` or use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button once user clicks.